# SUM of text in cells based on rules in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, sum, formula

I have created this Sheets to test this formula:

```
|   |    A     |   B  |   C   |  D |  
| 1 | Object   | Yes  | Maybe | No |  
| 2 | Object 1 | 50   | 25    | 0  |  
| 3 | Object 2 | 20   | 10    | 0  |  
| 4 | Object 3 | 20   | 10    | 0  |  
| 5 | Object 4 | 10   | 5     | 0  |
```

**Rules**

```
|   |    A      |    B     |   C      |    D     |    E     |    F    | G |  
| 1 | Article   | Object 1 | Object 2 | Object 3 | Object 4 | Total   |   |  
| 2 | Article 1 | 50       | 20       | 20       | 10       | 100     |   |  
| 3 | Article 2 | Yes      | Yes      | Yes      | Yes      | 100     |   |  
| 4 | Article 3 | Yes      | No       | No       | Yes      | 60      |   |  
| 5 | Article 4 | No       | Yes      | Yes      | No       | 40      |   |  
| 6 | Test      | No       | Yes      | Yes      | No       | #VALUE! |   |  
| 7 | Test2     | Yes      | Yes      | No       | Yes      | 50      |   |  
| 8 | Test3     | Yes      | Yes      | No       | Yes      | 70      | * |

* This works partially, but if No is selected the next Yes won't be calculated and breaks  
if first Object is not Yes. The example says 70 but should be 80.
```

**Sheet**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ydSfa4dpkTdcvwPPqGLRdQ9r-JZstB-hYS7J7tondUs/edit?usp=sharing

What I want to achieve is that the values listed in `Rules!` should correspond to `Yes/No` in `Sheet!` when it adds up the SUM.

For example in Sheet!, if I select `Yes, Yes, No, Yes` it should add up to `50 + 20 + 0 + 10 = 80`. As the first `Yes` equals `50`, followed by `20, 20, 10`, and any `No` equals `0`.

I know very basics formulas when it comes to spreadsheets, and what I have tried so far is the following, and it is also where I get stuck.

I want it to read `B8` through `E8`, see how many `Yes` is listed, and if any `Yes` is listed, compare it to `B2` through `B5`.

```
=SUMIF(B8:E8,"Yes",Rules!B2:B5)
```

The closest I have come is by ignoring the Rules sheet and to put the rules directly into the formula by repeating IF statements. This way it works, but I would still prefer to have the rules set by the Rules sheet.

```
=IF(B10="Yes",50+IF(C10="Yes",20+IF(D10="Yes",20+IF(E10="Yes",10,0))))
```

What I try it probably very incorrect, but as I said I have no idea how to proceed or fix it.

Does anyone have a suggestion for me?

Or if you need further explanation of what I want to achieve, if something is not clear, please let me know and I will try to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are after [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294):

```
=sumproduct(B$2:E$2,B3:E3="Yes")
```

in F3 of `Sheet`, copied down to suit, or perhaps:

```
=sumproduct(transpose(Rules!B$2:B$5),B3:E3="Yes")
```

Comment: Thank you pnuts, that works great!

Would you have any idea how to combine the two following, if `Maybe` would equal another set of rules listed besides `Yes` in Rules sheet. For example `30, 15, 10, 5`.

So `Yes, Maybe, Yes, Maybe` would sum up to `50, 15, 20, 5`.

    =sumproduct(transpose(Rules!B$2:B$5),B13:E13="Yes"
    =sumproduct(transpose(Rules!C$2:C$5),B13:E13="Maybe")

Comment: It seems all I needed was a plus-sign in between:

    =sumproduct(transpose(Rules!B$2:B$5),B13:E13="Yes")+(sumproduct(transpose(Rules!C$2:C$5),B13:E13="Maybe"))

Thank you once again for the solution pnuts!